# Having problems with negative monitor channel, intimidated!

Tags: kernel, wifi, linux-kernel

When I try this command:

`aireplay-ng -1 0 mon0 -a xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`

I get this output:

`No source MAC (-h) specified. Using the device MAC (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx)
17:51:23  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) on channel -1
17:51:23  Couldn't determine current channel for mon0, you should either force the operation with --ignore-negative-one or apply a kernel patch
Please specify an ESSID (-e).`

The `--ignore-negative-one` flag doesn't make any difference.

Obviously I've placed my card in monitor mode with `airmon-ng start wlan0`.

I've been looking around, and I've found forum threads where they seem to have found solutions:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/643788

But frankly, these discussions are all pretty obtuse and are talking about kernel patches. **I'm *extrememly* intimidated by the idea of a kernel patch!!**

What is a safe solution to these odd negative channel problems?

I'm having this problem with both Ubuntu and Kali Linux.